# Rubber ec2 deployment issue during create_staging step .. how to continue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails-4, rubber

I'm using Rubber gem to deploy my first rails app to an ec2 server. I had a problem during the  bundle install step when I called the 'cap rubber:create_staging' to establish my first server instance. My instance was created already so I logged in and made the necessary change on the ec2 server. Now I am not sure how to proceed in such a way that I can get my app up and running.

How do I determine what commands have yet to be run on my instance so that I can continue on and manually run them and get the server up and running from this point? Do I have to run the create_staging function and create another instance? Or is there an easy way to continue where it left off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `cap rubber:bootstrap` against your created instance, it's supposed to be idempotent and should just install all needed packages. Then `cap rubber:deploy:cold` to deploy.

`cap rubber:create_staging` runs:

`cap rubber:create`, `cap rubber:bootstrap`, `cap rubber:deploy:cold` and assigns the instance all roles.

If that fails you can always terminate the instance `cap rubber:destroy`.

[Railscasts #347](http://railscasts.com/episodes/347-rubber-and-amazon-ec2),
[Rubber commands (wiki)](https://github.com/rubber/rubber/wiki/Commands)